# Rails 3 - i18n model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

How do you set the model name in `config/locales/en.yml` for scaffolding like `<%= f.submit %>`?

Answer (score 5):

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    models:
      blog_post: "Post"
```